# Authorize.Net Partial Authorization Question

Tags: vb.net, sdk, authorize.net

I am making changes to my companies internal paysite in order to come into compliance with the new credit card regulations.  We  have decided that when we get a split tender transaction that comes through we want to get the remaining balance along with how much was on the card to start out with and send that info back to the customer service rep with a message relaying the need for another payment source along with the remaining balance and the amount that was originally on the card.

Instead of chaining the transactions together with the split tender Id we have decided we would like to finalize each split tender transaction with a prior_auth_capture and then request the next payment source and amount and process that transaction in the same manner.  I know that we are side stepping the functionality some but those are my orders.

My questions are, is this feasible and possible and how do you do this in code? I am using the C# SDK to implement this in VB.NET 2008

My thoughts are that I would have to process the transaction for the amount passed as a auth_capture transaction and then some how do the prior_auth_transaction with a zero amount or something?

How would this work?

Thanks for much for your help.

James

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible to do. The purpose of split tender payments is to logically group together split payments into one transaction. By breaking it up into multiple transactions it can get confusing for you, the users, and the processor. Especially if you have issues getting the user to make full payment on their transaction. Failing to void the other transactions would be very problematic. This almost certainly will result in an increased exposure to chargebacks.